# View logbook notes taken today, this week

Tags: org-mode

I wonder if it is possible to get a list of notes taken today or for given period that are stored in `:LOGBOOK:` drawer?

Comment: From agenda files? From the current buffer? From some other collection of Org mode files?

Comment: Ideally from agenda files in my case